# No module named django_river

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have an issue when running pip install -r requirements.txt and got no module named django_river.

I tried installing the package pip install django_river but it gives error, package does not exist.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try installing the package:

```
pip install django-river
```

This should work out

Comment: I have tried that but i still get another error "no module named river_admin"

Comment: Alright, I have edited the answer for this new error